# Blazor httpClient failing to make external API call

Tags: api, rest, blazor, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to make a simple REST API call but it seems security policies are stopping me and I don't know how to fix it. The code makes a call to an open API to get a joke. However I get the following error:
**dotnet.6.0.11.pbddgabtj1.js:1 Refused to connect to 'http://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random' because it violates the document's Content Security Policy.**

I have added the content security policy to my header in wwwroot/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
          content="base-uri 'self';
               block-all-mixed-content;
               default-src 'self';
               img-src data: https:;
               object-src 'none';
               script-src 'self'
                          'sha256-v8v3RKRPmN4odZ1CWM5gw80QKPCCWMcpNeOmimNL2AA='
                          'unsafe-eval';
               style-src 'self'
                         'unsafe-inline';
               upgrade-insecure-requests;">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">Loading...</div>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The component that does the call looks like this:

```
@page "/"
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>
<br />
<h4>Joke of the day:</h4>
<p>@joke</p>

@code{
    string joke = "No Joke";
    private readonly HttpClient clientHttp;

    public Index()
    {
        clientHttp = new HttpClient();
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync(){
        var url = new Uri("http://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random");
        joke = "";
        try
        {
            var result = await clientHttp.GetAsync(url);
            joke = result.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to get the joke. Error: ", e.Message);            
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(joke))
            joke = "No Joke";
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: change it to https. `https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random`

Comment: Sadly, I tried that. Didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. You need to whitelist the API call.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="base-uri 'self';
           block-all-mixed-content;
           default-src 'self';
           font-src 'self';
           connect-src 'self' 
                    https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random;
           img-src data: https:;
           object-src 'none';
           script-src 'self'
                      'sha256-v8v3RKRPmN4odZ1CWM5gw80QKPCCWMcpNeOmimNL2AA='
                      'unsafe-eval';
           style-src 'self'
                     'unsafe-inline';
           upgrade-insecure-requests;">
```